# What is the diode current when used in clipping/clamping

Tags: power-supply, diodes

The rule of thumb is that when a diode is fully on, it looks like a short circuit (ideally).  So (to make this easy), say I have 100 V source and a diode which breaks down at 10V.  If my power supply/source impedance is 1 Ohm, will the current through my diode be:

1. I = (Vsupply - Vdiode)/Rsupply = (100 - 10)/1 = 90/1 = 90 Amps, or
2. I = Vsupply/Rsupply = 100/1 = 100 Amps?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current will be the same for all parts of the circuit, and in this case be about 90A as the diode can be considered to be a low resistance 10V drop.